# Combine two arrays into one by matching elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have two arrays. One fetched from an API the other fetched from firebase. They both have a similar key inside of them, that being the tld. As seen below.

**API Array**

```
[
 {
  "tld" : "com",
  "tld_type": 1,
 },
  "tld" : "org",
  "tld_type" : 1,
 }
]
```

**Firebase Array**

```
[
  {
    "TLD" : "com",
    "register_price" : 14.99
  },
  {
    "TLD" : "org",
    "register_price" : 15.99
  }
]
```

I want to combine these two arrays into one and return it like below

```
[
    {
        "tld" : "com",
        "tld_type" : 1,
        "register_price" : 14.99
    },
    {
        "tld" : "org",
        "tld_type" : 1,
        "register_price" : 15.99
    }
]
```

I've done some google searching and found `concact` but that doesn't seem to be using the key to find the match. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no unique method for solving that kind of issue. You'll have to loop through all elements and add `register_price` property if that property exists in firebase array. In shortest possible:

```
let combined = apiArray.map(ele=>{
    let machedElement = fbArray.find(e => e.TLD === ele.tld)
    if(machedElement != undefined) ele.register_price = machedElement.register_price
    return ele
})
```

In case if you want to merge all properties not only register_price:

```
let combined = apiArray.map(ele=>{
    let machedElement = fbArray.find(e => e.TLD === ele.tld)
    if(machedElement != undefined) {
       let mergedObject = Object.assign(ele, machedElement)
       return mergedObject
    }else{
       return ele
    }
})
```

Comment: What if I just want to take all the elements from both arrays and merge them? as in, not declaring `ele.register_price` and just pushing them both together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and create a new object whose keys and values will be from the other two arrays and return that object. `map` will create a new array of objects

```js
let api = [{
    "tld": "com",
    "tld_type": 1,
  },
  {
    "tld": "org",
    "tld_type": 1,
  }
]
let fb = [{
    "TLD": "com",
    "register_price": 14.99
  },
  {
    "TLD": "org",
    "register_price": 15.99
  }
]

let k = api.map(function(item, index) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.tld = item.tld;
  obj['tld_type'] = item['tld_type'];
  obj['register_price'] = fb[index]['register_price']
  return obj;

});
console.log(k)
```

Comment: That is super awesome! Only problem I see with it is that both indexes are not the same in both arrays??